# "I want user to access some of the views in my screen via in-App purchase only."

Tags: ios

I am using the In-App Purchase , I have added the StoreKit Framework and also product identifier set to In-App-Purchase at iTune.
I want to download the some screen of my app if it permitted by In-App Purchase from iTunes.
I have done all the code which is required.

My question is: "I want user to access some of the views in my screen via in-App purchase only."?

Comment: What have you tried ? You say "I have done all the code which is required". Why do you need help ?

Comment: Note that putting a question mark at the end of a sentence does not automatically make it a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, all you need to do is something like this:

```
if (user_has_purchased_content) {
     [self presentModalViewController:myController animated:YES];
} else {
     // Don't..
}
```